# Can't get footer color all the way to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want the black part of my footer to continue all the way to the bottom of the page. Instead, the grey is there. How can I change this? I've tried changing the height to 100% but there's no change.

```css
/* -- Footer Styles -- */

footer {
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  background: #222;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

footer h1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #DDD;
}

footer article {
  width: 10%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: none;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DDD;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#cpyrt {
  clear: both;
  background: #010101;
  color: #666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #9B0F00;
}

#cpyrt ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h1>Dungeon<br>Dudes</h1>

  <article>
    <h6>Quick Links</h6>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h6>Support</h6>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h6>Follow Us</h6>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <article id="cpyrt">
    <p>&copy; 2018 Dungeon Dudes | All Rights Reserved</p>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</footer>
```

[Webpage Footer Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7dBU.png)

The Picture shows what it currently looks like. I'm trying to get the grey bit at the bottom to be black without changing the color of the whole footer element.

Comment: It'll be easier to get help if your sample code was actually a 'code snippet' people could run and edit directly.

Comment: You haven't provided us enough code to solve your issue, we need more context, please provide the rest of the HTML & CSS for th page.

Comment: the code isn't enough create a snippet and then the community will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined colour `#222` in `footer` selector, again you are overriding the colour of `footer` in the ID selector that is `#cpyrt` . 
Follow the below css

```
#cpyrt {
  clear: both;
/*   background: #222; */ //-->remove element
  color: #666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #9B0F00;
}
```

See the [Live Demo](https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/vaoPXJ?editors=1100)

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: My issue is that I'm trying to make the bottom half of the footer black and the top half grey. I don't want it all grey. Sorry is I was unclear